# get separate string from ajax error handling

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have Respons text, catch from Ajax Error.responseText.

```
error: function (data) {
             alert(data.responseText);
            }
```

the value from data.responseText =

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<title>Database Error</title>\n<style type=\"text/css\">\n\n::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }\n::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }\n::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }\n\nbody {\n\tbackground-color: #fff;\n\tmargin: 40px;\n\tfont: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n\tcolor: #4F5155;\n}\n\na {\n\tcolor: #003399;\n\tbackground-color: transparent;\n\tfont-weight: normal;\n}\n\nh1 {\n\tcolor: #444;\n\tbackground-color: transparent;\n\tborder-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;\n\tfont-size: 19px;\n\tfont-weight: normal;\n\tmargin: 0 0 14px 0;\n\tpadding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;\n}\n\ncode {\n\tfont-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;\n\tfont-size: 12px;\n\tbackground-color: #f9f9f9;\n\tborder: 1px solid #D0D0D0;\n\tcolor: #002166;\n\tdisplay: block;\n\tmargin: 14px 0 14px 0;\n\tpadding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;\n}\n\n#container {\n\tmargin: 10px;\n\tborder: 1px solid #D0D0D0;\n\t-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;\n}\n\np {\n\tmargin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n\t<div id=\"container\">\n\t\t<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>\n\t\t<p>Error Number: 1062</p><p>Duplicate entry '60-2017' for key 'PRIMARY'</p><p>INSERT INTO `table` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`) VALUES ('60', '2017', '60_2017_Permohonan_d2030211.pdf', '2018-06-24 16:43:49')</p><p>Filename: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fol/models/rek/m_rek.php</p><p>Line Number: 47</p>\t</div>\n</body>\n</html>"
```

How to Retreive text "Error Number: 1062" from text Above..?

Thank You

Comment: Are you in control of how that error message is created/sent from the server?

Comment: Looks like your are coding your Ajax API script like it was a web page and not an API. Show us that code as well

Comment: You have unique index constraint in your db table but you are trying to insert new row with same value of an existing row. Check line 47 of m_rek model.

Comment: @Tpojka The question has nothing to do with how the query is made, it is about extracting a substring from an error message.

Comment: @LGSon I think that is wrong approach - it is clear code is not checking one of most important things and that is correct data check before insert. That one should be solved in first place. Output is way lower regarding importance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like this :

You can get it by using javascript function `exec()`

```
error: function (data) 
{
   var errorText = /Error Number:\s\d*/.exec(data.responseText);
   alert(errorText);
}
```

Working demo : https://jsfiddle.net/o2be0md6/4/

For more : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_exec.asp

Comment: someone showing one's frustration by downvoting this answer, for  who downvote this answer i never said OP to accept my answer, if my answer is really bad i can remove it from here , just tell

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you might use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

The text of the error number is inside the `div` with id `container` and is the first `<p>` so you could get that element using [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

You code would look like

```
error: function (data) {
    let parser = new DOMParser();
    let doc = parser.parseFromString(data.responseText, "text/html");
    alert(doc.querySelector("#container p").innerHTML);
}
```

```js
let parser = new DOMParser();
var data = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<title>Database Error</title>\n<style type=\"text/css\">\n\n::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }\n::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }\n::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }\n\nbody {\n\tbackground-color: #fff;\n\tmargin: 40px;\n\tfont: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n\tcolor: #4F5155;\n}\n\na {\n\tcolor: #003399;\n\tbackground-color: transparent;\n\tfont-weight: normal;\n}\n\nh1 {\n\tcolor: #444;\n\tbackground-color: transparent;\n\tborder-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;\n\tfont-size: 19px;\n\tfont-weight: normal;\n\tmargin: 0 0 14px 0;\n\tpadding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;\n}\n\ncode {\n\tfont-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;\n\tfont-size: 12px;\n\tbackground-color: #f9f9f9;\n\tborder: 1px solid #D0D0D0;\n\tcolor: #002166;\n\tdisplay: block;\n\tmargin: 14px 0 14px 0;\n\tpadding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;\n}\n\n#container {\n\tmargin: 10px;\n\tborder: 1px solid #D0D0D0;\n\t-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;\n}\n\np {\n\tmargin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n\t<div id=\"container\">\n\t\t<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>\n\t\t<p>Error Number: 1062</p><p>Duplicate entry '60-2017' for key 'PRIMARY'</p><p>INSERT INTO `table` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`) VALUES ('60', '2017', '60_2017_Permohonan_d2030211.pdf', '2018-06-24 16:43:49')</p><p>Filename: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fol/models/rek/m_rek.php</p><p>Line Number: 47</p>\t</div>\n</body>\n</html>";
let doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/html");
console.log(doc.querySelector("#container p").innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this snippet might help you.

```js
var responseData = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<title>Database Error</title>\n<style type=\"text/css\">\n\n::selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }\n::moz-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }\n::webkit-selection{ background-color: #E13300; color: white; }\n\nbody {\n\tbackground-color: #fff;\n\tmargin: 40px;\n\tfont: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;\n\tcolor: #4F5155;\n}\n\na {\n\tcolor: #003399;\n\tbackground-color: transparent;\n\tfont-weight: normal;\n}\n\nh1 {\n\tcolor: #444;\n\tbackground-color: transparent;\n\tborder-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;\n\tfont-size: 19px;\n\tfont-weight: normal;\n\tmargin: 0 0 14px 0;\n\tpadding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;\n}\n\ncode {\n\tfont-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;\n\tfont-size: 12px;\n\tbackground-color: #f9f9f9;\n\tborder: 1px solid #D0D0D0;\n\tcolor: #002166;\n\tdisplay: block;\n\tmargin: 14px 0 14px 0;\n\tpadding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;\n}\n\n#container {\n\tmargin: 10px;\n\tborder: 1px solid #D0D0D0;\n\t-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;\n}\n\np {\n\tmargin: 12px 15px 12px 15px;\n}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n\t<div id=\"container\">\n\t\t<h1>A Database Error Occurred</h1>\n\t\t<p>Error Number: 1062</p><p>Duplicate entry '60-2017' for key 'PRIMARY'</p><p>INSERT INTO `table` (`f1`, `f2`, `f3`, `f4`) VALUES ('60', '2017', '60_2017_Permohonan_d2030211.pdf', '2018-06-24 16:43:49')</p><p>Filename: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/fol/models/rek/m_rek.php</p><p>Line Number: 47</p>\t</div>\n</body>\n</html>";
        
console.log($(responseData ).find("#container,p").first().text());
```